# more than n eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am learning diagonalization of matrices. We are given the following theorem:

> If $A$ is an $n\times n $ matrix with $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then $a$ is diagonalizable

Now the proof is:

> let $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ be eigenvectors corresponding to the $n$ distinct eigenvalues of $a$. (Why could there not me *more* than $n$ such eigenvectors?) $v_1, v_2,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly independent, so by (a specific theorem) A is diagonalizable.

Now the question posed in the proof has gotten my thinking, why cant there be more than n eigenvectors correspdonign to n distinct eigenvalues? because an eigenvalue can correspond to only  one eigenvalues? because they are distinct?

Comment: If there is one eigenvector belonging to someeigenvalue then there are as many (belonging to the same eigenvalue) as non-zero scalars the field has. What the posting actually says (apparently, at least, this is the intention conveyed by that word "such" there) is that eigenvectors belonging to **different** eigevalues are *linearly independent* ...

Comment: If $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, then the maximum number of eigenvalues is given by the degree of the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)=det(A-\lambda I)$, i.e. $n$. As the eigenvalues of $A$ are the roots $p(\lambda)=0$, then you have $n$ in general complex eigenvalues, counted with multiplicities.

Comment: @Avitus, he's not asking about eigenvalues but about eigevectors...

Comment: @DonAntonio you are right: there are already answers on eigenvectors down under; I thought that fixing ideas on eigenvalues could be useful :)

Comment: always helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is late, and the answers given here are great, but based on the poster's last comment, and the comment left by epoweritheta, I think there is still some misunderstanding here.

It is true that you can get more than one eigenvector for a single eigenvalue: consider the matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$$

However, you can have at most $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors for a given matrix. There are many ways to see why this has to be so, but here's one: An $n \times n $ represents a linear operator, that is, it is a linear transformation from an $n$-dimensional vector space to itself. Now, in an $n$-dimensional vector space, any set of vectors having more than $n$ vectors is DEPENDENT. To see this, you could set up the linear independence equation, $$c_1\vec{v_1} + c_2 \vec{v_2} + \cdots + c_n \vec{v_n} + \cdots + c_{n+m} \vec{v_{n+m}} = \vec{0}$$ You will find that when you augment the matrix for that system, you will get an $n \times (n+m)$ matrix and hence you will have less pivots than there are columns upon performing Gaussian elimination. This gives rise to a solution that depends on parameters, which means you won't have a unique solution and hence you get dependence.

So having $n$ eigenvalues, each will have at least one eigenvector (by construction--if you want to know why each eigenvalue will have at least one, you can ask me--the short answer is we find eigenvalues by setting up a homogeneous system whose coefficient matrix has determinant zero, hence by the equivalence theorem, this system is guaranteed to have a non-zero vector-solution, in fact, it will have infinitely many such solutions), but there will be only $n$ such vectors that are linearly independent. And then you can apply the theorem that says having $n$ linearly independent vectors implies being diagonalizable (and vice versa).

Comment: You absolute hero. This was in my undergraduate year, I graduated in January and I sitll enjoy your answer very much.

Answer (score 2):

Who said there can't be more than $n$ eigenvectors? Nothing in the passage you quoted depends on there being exactly $n$ eigenvectors; all that's required is that there are (at least) $n$ eigenvectors.

Having said that, eigenvectors belonging to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent. If you have more than $n$ eigenvectors, then any two belonging to the same eigenvalue will be linearly dependent, and so of no use for diagonalization.

Comment: oh i get it, the n _distinct_ eigenvalues need at least n corresponding eigenvectors, because an eigenvalue needs an eigenvector to satisfy $Av=\lambda v$ , doesnt really matter which. as long as it satisfies the equation.

Answer (score 2):

Why could there not be more than n ***INDEPENDENT*** eigenvectors for a *n×n* matrix ?